# Remote modal not displaying header and footer in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootrap 3 and remote modal to load a remote page. The code is similar to that specified in documentation. The content of the page is loading in modal but modal-header and modal-footer which contains close button are not shown.

Trigger:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-remote="remote.html" video.id %}" 
data-target="#myModal"><button class="btn btn-success" >Edit details </button></a>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te"></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

remote.html:

```
<p style="background-color:#ffffff">My name is duip </p>
```

Comment: I think you need to return the complete `modal-dialog` element from the remote.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remote.html has to return the complete `modal-dialog` content.

> remote: If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded via
>   jQuery's load method and injected into the root of the modal element.

So update remote.html to

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p style="background-color:#ffffff">My name is duip </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/45Z3qh?p=preview)

Comment: Ok, I got it. But its not possible to modify the remote modal as it is also being used to serve other content. Is there any other way apart from adding modal-dialog content to remote.html

Answer (score 2):

As @ArunPJohny said, you have to return the whole `modal-dialog` content. You can play with layouts to serve the same content wrapped into different boxes, for instance

```
http://example.com/remote.html?layout=modal     # to use a modal layout
http://example.com/remote.html?layout=false     # to return the bare content
```

etc.

Then in your controller action check for `params[:layout]` and render using the correct layout:

```
render layout: 'modal'
```

or

```
render layout: false
```

etc.

Your `view/layouts/modal.html.erb` should be

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p style="background-color:#ffffff"><%= yield %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already solved the problem using similar approach as you suggested.